# How to get the return data of a save with Ember Data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm using Ember.js with ember-data to make a GUI for a self made API.

I've been following this [tutorial](http://coderberry.me/blog/2013/07/08/authentication-with-emberjs-part-2/) to handle authentication but I want to use ember-data instead of custom jQuery requests.

One thing I have to do is to call the API to create a new session, by sending email and password, and the API sends me back an API Key object.

Here is my LoginController handling the loginUser action (it's CoffeeScript) :

```
App.LoginController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  actions:
    loginUser: ->
      session = @store.createRecord 'session',
        email:    @get 'email'
        password: @get 'password'
      session.save()
```

Here is the result I get when creating a session:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": "525fa0286c696c0b14040000",
            "email": "john.doe@mydomain.com",
            "first_name": "John",
            "surname": "Doe"
        }
    ],
    "api_key": {
        "id": "526e464c6c696c07d2000000",
        "type": "session",
        "key": "6b824d6a-a065-4b6f-bb28-5c19389760f8",
        "expires_at": "2013-10-28T11:41:08+00:00",
        "user_id": "525fa0286c696c0b14040000"
    }
}
```

I have Session, ApiKey and User models. I can create the session, but the thing I don't understand is how to access the return value of the `save()` method.

I know that my ApiKey and User are loaded somewhere because I get an error after `save()` if their respective Ember model don't exist but I don't know how to access them.

I've tried to use `save()` callbacks like `then()` or `didCreate` event but there's a lack of documentation about arguments passed to these callbacks and how to use them.

- Ember.js **1.1.2**
- Ember Data **1.0.0.beta.3**

**EDIT:**
I've tried to create an actuel Session model on my API, resulting in this JSON output:

```
{
    "api_keys": [
        {
            "id": "526f69526c696c07d2110000",
            "type": "session",
            "key": "4c26af37-2b21-49c2-aef5-5850a396da0b",
            "expires_at": "2013-10-29T08:22:50+00:00",
            "user_id": "525fa0286c696c0b14040000"
        }
    ],
    "users": [
        {
            "id": "525fa0286c696c0b14040000",
            "email": "john.doe@coreye.fr",
            "first_name": "John",
            "surname": "Doe"
        }
    ],
    "session": {
        "id": "526f6e666c696c18c0010000",
        "api_key_id": "526f69526c696c07d2110000"
    }
}
```

(note the root element is now `session`)

It doesn't work better because now my save action leads to the following error (not in the console but `then` points to error callback):

```
Object function () { [...] } has no method 'eachTransformedAttribute'
```

I get this error, the relation between Session and ApiKey being declared in Ember Data models or not...

Answer (score 0):

Your second example JSON looks better: since you are saving a Session, I would expect a session node in the response and other models to be side loaded. You can access the saved session after it's saved by using a promise callback:

```
session.save().then (savedSession) =>
  console.log savedSession.api_key.key
```

Since you have `_id` relationship keys in your JSON, I assume you are using the ActiveModel adapter and its default serializer:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend()
```